# Getting date in different format while validation from date in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, date-format

I am using jQuery datepicker for a textfield in my application.I am able to insert data properly in (dd-MM-yy) format.But the  problem is getting date in diiferent format(date and time with timezone) back to the text field while validating which leads to an exception.

**Student.java**

```html
public class Student {
 private final static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(Student.class);
private Integer sid;

private String firstName;

private String middleName;

private String lastName;

private String fatherName;

private String motherName;

private Date dateOfBirth;

private Integer admissionNo;

private Date dateOfJoining;

private String standard;

private String section;

private String medium;

private Address address;
```

**StudentController.java**

```css
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/student")
    public class StudentController {
     
     private final static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(StudentController.class);
     
     @Autowired
     private StudentService studentService;
     
     @Autowired
     private StudentValidator studentValidator;
     
     @RequestMapping("/form")
     public ModelAndView getForm(@ModelAttribute Student student,Model model){
      initModelList(model);
      
      logger.info("This  is a message");
     return new ModelAndView("form");
     }
     
     @RequestMapping("/register")
     public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult,SessionStatus status){
      
      studentService.addStudent(student);
      initModelList(model);
      studentValidator.validate(student, bindingResult);
      if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
       return "form";
      }else{
      logger.info("Student added successfully...");
      status.setComplete();
      return "redirect:list";
      }
     }
     
     @InitBinder
     protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
         SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
         dateFormat.setLenient(true);
         binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
                 dateFormat, false));
     }
     
     private void initModelList(Model model){
         List<String> standardList=new ArrayList<String>();
          standardList.add("--Select--");
      standardList.add("I");
      standardList.add("II");
      standardList.add("III");
      standardList.add("IV");
      standardList.add("V");
      standardList.add("VI");
      standardList.add("VII");
      standardList.add("VIII");
      standardList.add("IX");
      standardList.add("X");
      model.addAttribute("standard",standardList);
      
      List<String> mediumList=new ArrayList<String>();
      
      mediumList.add("Telugu");
      mediumList.add("English");
      model.addAttribute("medium",mediumList);
      
      List<String> sectionList =new ArrayList<String>();
      sectionList.add("--Select--");
      sectionList.add("A");
      sectionList.add("B");
      sectionList.add("C");
      sectionList.add("D");
      sectionList.add("E");
      model.addAttribute("section", sectionList);
      
      List<String> cityList=new ArrayList<String>();
      cityList.add("--Select--");
      cityList.add("Bangalore");
      cityList.add("Hyderabad");
      cityList.add("Chennai");
      cityList.add("Mumbai");
      model.addAttribute("city", cityList);
      
      List<String> genderList =new ArrayList<String>();
      //genderList.add("--Select--");
      genderList.add("Male");
      genderList.add("Female");
     }
     
     @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
     @RequestMapping("/list")
     public ModelAndView listStudents(){
      List studentsList=studentService.listStudents();
      return new ModelAndView("/list","studentsList",studentsList);
     }
     
     @RequestMapping("/delete")
     public ModelAndView deleteStudent(@RequestParam Integer sid){
      studentService.deleteStudent(sid);
      return new ModelAndView("redirect:list");
     }
     
     @RequestMapping("/edit")
     public ModelAndView editStudent(@RequestParam Integer sid){
      Student studentObject=studentService.getStudent(sid);
      return new ModelAndView("edit","studentObject",studentObject);
     }
     
     @RequestMapping("/update")
     public ModelAndView updateSudent(@ModelAttribute Student student){
      studentService.updateStudent(student);
      return new ModelAndView("redirect:list");
     }
     
    }
```

```css
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>School Management System</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/hello.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/sms_validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/css/styles.css"/>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: "dd-MM-yy"
    });
    
  });
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="content">


<div class="content_heading">Student Registration Form</div>

<p>This is a paragraph</p>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Date</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<form:form id="registerForm" modelAttribute="student" method="post" action="register" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<fieldset>
<legend>Student Details:</legend>  
<table class="form_table">

<tr><td><form:label path="sid">Studet Id</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="sid" placeholder="Enter Student Id"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="sid" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="firstName" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="lastName"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="lastName" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="middleName">Middle Name</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="middleName"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="middleName" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><form:label path="fatherName">Father Name</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="fatherName"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="fatherName" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="motherName">Mother Name</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="motherName"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="motherName" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>

<tr><td><form:label path="dateOfBirth">Date Of birth</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="dateOfBirth" class="datepicker"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="dateOfBirth" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="admissionNo">Admission No</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="admissionNo"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="admissionNo" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><form:label path="dateOfJoining">DateOfJoining</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="dateOfJoining" class="datepicker"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="dateOfJoining" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="standard">Standard</form:label></td>
<td><form:select path="standard" >
<form:options items="${standard}"/>
</form:select></td>
<td><form:errors  path="standard" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><form:label path="section">Section</form:label></td>
<td><form:select path="section" items="${section}"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="section" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="medium">Medium</form:label></td>
<td><form:radiobuttons path="medium" items="${medium}"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="medium" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Addres Details:</legend>
<table class="form_table">
<tr><td><form:label path="address.doorNo">DoorNo</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="address.doorNo"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="address.doorNo" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="address.streetName">StreetName</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="address.streetName"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="address.streetName" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>

<tr><td><form:label path="address.addressLine">AddressLine</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="address.addressLine"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="address.addressLine" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="address.city">City</form:label></td>
<td><form:select path="address.city" items="${city}"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="address.city" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>

<tr><td><form:label path="address.district">District</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="address.district"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="address.district" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="address.state">State</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="address.state"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="address.state" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>

<tr><td><form:label path="address.pin">Pin</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="address.pin"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="address.pin" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="address.phone">Phone</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="address.phone"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="address.phone" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>

<tr><td><form:label path="address.email">Email</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="address.email"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="address.email" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="address.country">Country</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="address.country"/></td>
<td><form:errors  path="address.country" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>

<tr><td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form:form>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please solve my problem ,Thanks in advance..

Comment: But the problem is getting date in diiferent format(date and time with timezone) back to the text field while validating which leads to an exception    I don't understand your point here,can you just tell us what value you are receiving at your Spring layer or in Database..and one more thing, i would like to know,is exception coming in your JSP page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My input is in the format 04-nov-2014. After submitting my form. when showing validation messages.. the data returned back to the date field is in the format Tue Nov 04 00:00:00 IST 2014.I am able to insert data into database in the format 04-nov-2014 if i dont get any validation messages.. Here the problem is, date format is being changed whenever i get validation messages.If i submit the form with the changed format date.. I am getting the fallowing exception

Comment: BindException:org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors Field error in object 'student' on field 'dateOfBirth': rejected value [Tue Nov 04 00:00:00 IST 2014]; codes [typeMismatch.student.dateOfBirth,typeMismatch.dateOfBirth,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [student.dateOfBirth,dateOfBirth]; arguments []; default message [dateOfBirth]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'dateOfBirth';

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to add below initbinder inside your controller,which will convert to the required format.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yy"), true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```

Also use below annotation for date field in Student class.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMMM-yy")
private Date dateOfBirth;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMMM-yy")
private Date dateOfJoining;
```

Comment: I tried those things earlier and now also.. It is leaving me with fallowing exception..

org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors Field error in object 'student' on field 'dateOfBirth': rejected value [04-November-2014]; codes [typeMismatch.student.dateOfBirth,typeMismatch.dateOfBirth,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [student.dateOfBirth,dateOfBirth]; arguments []; default message [dateOfBirth]];

Comment: default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'dateOfBirth'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date for value '04-November-2014'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse '04-November-2014'] Field error in object 'student' on field 'dateOfJoining': rejected value [11-November-2014]; codes [typeMismatch.student.dateOfJoining,

Comment: just updated my answer,i have changed the date format from dd-MM-yy to dd-MMMM-yy,i think it should work now,can you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

```css
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMMM-yy")
private Date dateOfBirth;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMMM-yy")
private Date dateOfJoining;
```

These Lines solved my problem... Thanks Mr. @RE350